# Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'Unity/GlesHelper.h' file not found error in Xcode 5.1.1 from Unity

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, ngui

I converted my Unity 4.5.1f3 game project to iOS and opened the same in XCode 5.1.1.

To resolve the issues with Mach-O linker error I kept the Library and Framework search paths blank in build settings as I have done successfully in other XCode projects.

This removed the Mach-O linker error. However the above error `Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'Unity/GlesHelper.h' file not found` error in Xcode 5.1.1 from Unity is reported now.

I have tried the following build settings:

1. setting Always search user paths to Yes
2. adding an entry to the Header search path: 
   `$(SRCROOT)/Classes/Unity`

I am not using any plugin other than NGUI 2.7 for Unity.

The screenshot of XCode with the error reported in the editor sub window is available at the link http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-unity-gleshelper-h-file-not-found-error-in-xcode-5-1-1-from-unity.267386/

Kindly share your feedback on resolving this issue expediently. Please let me know if you need any more specific data to address this issue.

Comment: did you find any solution related to this error, as of now i am facing the same error

Comment: The way I could address the issue was to create a new unity project and copy paste assets from the buggy project. I am not sure what could be the source of the issue, but I suspect it would have to do with the project editor settings, or some project related settings, as in this new project that works when converted and built on iOS the assets have been copy pasted from the old project. Will post if I can pin point the source of the issue.